# Как вытащить из итератора значение?

Tags: итераторы, c++

```
char path_to_;
typedef vector < fs::path > vec;    // store paths,  
vec v;              // so we can sort them later

copy(fs::directory_iterator(p), fs::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));
for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()), it_end(v.end()); it != it_end; ++it) {
    cout << "   " << *it << 'n';
    path_to_ = вот тут it ???
}
```

Comment: Значение элемента контейнера? Так у Вас уже написано в операторе вывода -- `*it` (строка `cout << "   " << *it << '\n';`)

Comment: Что такое ``path_to_ ``? Что оно должно хранить?

Comment: path_to_ -- переменная. Да ещё и неправильного типа. Д.б. `fs::path path_to_` или `fs::path *path_to_;`

Answer (score 2):

Да все разобрался истина тут    out << "   " << *it << 'n';
как и писал alexlz